# What is a ViewController?

Tags: hyperlink, viewcontroller, xcode3.2

I am a newbie, and I am wondering what a ViewController is. I've tried to look at the description, but I find it too complicated. I'm working on Xcode 3 and am trying to link two pages together.

Comment: You should consider upgrading to a newer version of Xcode, you are drastically limiting the iOS versions you can develop for considering the newest version is Xcode 4.3.2 for iOS 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged this question with xcode3.2 i'll assume you're asking about UIViewController.

It's one of the [UIKit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKit_Framework/_index.html) classes.

One of its most important properties is its `view` (which is an instance of [UIView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)) that usually holds one or more subviews.
What differentiates it from simple UIView are its methods for memory management, handling appearance, implementation in [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) hierarchy...

The *dull* information on `UIViewController` can be found here: [UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926)

You're definetly want to take a look at [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457) and [View Controller Catalog for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313).